# building a C++ project on Linux platform (or more specifically: building CLIPS on Ubuntu 9.10)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I'm in the process of moving from XP to Linux. (I'm new to Linux)

I have succesfully installed CLIPs on Ubuntu, using the SPM. I would however, like to build CLIPS from the sources - since I will be extending its current functionality.

I have downloaded the CLIPS sources (v6.2.4) from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/

in to my /home/morpheous/projects/CLIPS folder, and I now want to build it. However, I am new to the gnu build tools and make (I have already run sudo aptitude install build-essential).

Can anyone offer any help/instructions on how I may build CLIPS (I suspect that I may need to build the X11 interface as well - but that is a lower priority for now)

Answer (score 3):

Typically you use the make program to build the app from sources, nearly all C/C++ apps provide a makefile that describes what, and how, to build.

In general, you'd type

```
./configure
make
make install
```

These will:

- run the configure shell script that sets up your build environment, setting things like which CPU and OS you're using.
- use the standard-named makefile that comes with the project to build the source code.
- use the special 'install' target in the makefile to copy the necessary files to their final resting places.

Edit: [Here's a brief description](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/current/smith.html) of the process from the Linux Documentation Project.

BTW, with regard to dependant projects, I would try to install them directly from your package repository (ie yum or apt-get) because you often do not need to build them, just to use them. You may need to get the development sources (eg the header files and libs) sometimes, but you can get these from the repos too - they will be called something like xxx-devel, eg. "kernel-devel", so yum install kernel-devel will get you what you need to develop kernel modules without having to build the kernel itself.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu (Debian) way to do this is as follows:

```
apt-get source clips
apt-get build-dep clips
cd clips-6.24
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Typically if you want to use the non patched source you:

```
./configure
make install
```

Comment: This looks nice and sweet - could be what I am looking for. 

Could you clarify though, what you mean by "if you want to use the non patched source .."

My understanding is that this would be how to build my locally modified files - correct?